# Getting an object's pixel area in Photoshop

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, photos

Is there a way to get an oddly-shaped object's pixel area in CS5? Eg. Circle/ellipse. Or, if there's some easy-to-automate way to do it outside of Photoshop.

I know it's possible to use a magic wand selection and see the height+width in the info panel, but that only works accurately for rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have CS5, but if you go into the histogram in the stats section there is a stat called pixel, which is the total number of pixels used to make the calculations.  So if you make the section before going into the histogram you should be able to get the pixel count of a non-rectangular object.  To make it easier I would probably move the section to a new layer so that you know you have exactly what you want.

[Adobe Documentation for CS3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-768b.html)

Answer (score 1):

In CS3: Analysis > Record Measurements > Look at the area column.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to script something (Photoshop is scriptable) to count the total number of pixels in the rectangle, then subtract the number of pixels that have 0% fill.

Other than that, I think you'll need to brush up on your calculus.